# IMEI not passing Luhn Checksum

Tags: java, checksum, imei, luhn

I have the following code for validating IMEIs (not SV)

```
public static boolean luhnc(char[] digits) {
    int sum = 0, s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length - 1; i += 2) {
        s = (digits[i+1] - '0') * 2;
        sum += (s > 10 ? s - 9 : s) + (digits[i] - '0');
    }
    return 10 - (sum % 10) == (digits[digits.length-1] - '0');
}
```

Almost every IMEI checks out except for my Samsung Galaxy Note 4.

I do not want to post it here for obvious reasons  but at the same time I need someone to verify that it works.

Perhaps it's my implementation that's not right.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a point you miss in `Luhn algo` after do the `*2` operation, it's

- if the number is `>=10` (and not `>`), because `10` becomes `0` instead of `1`

---

So fix like this (I extract it in a new line to be clear for you) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length - 1; i += 2) {
    s = (digits[i + 1] - '0') * 2;                 
    sum += (s >= 10 ? s - 9 : s) + (digits[i] - '0');
}
```

---

Also I would recommand to use a `int[]` instead of `char[]` to remove the `- '0'` everywhere

Comment: Ah. Thanks.  So it's  *>=* and not *>*. It validates now. Thanks.  Also, conversely, we can subtract 9 to get the same result of adding the two digits of the greater number. :)

Comment: @TheRealChx101 ha yes you're right, I never think about doing that way ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the library from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/checkdigit/LuhnCheckDigit.html).

`org.apache.commons.validator.routines.checkdigit.LuhnCheckDigit.LUHN_CHECK_DIGIT.isValid(imei)`